# Reaching users of facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app that is connected to facebook graph, and thus have a corresponding facebook app. I'm looking for a means of communicating with the users of my app through their facebook feed.

So far I've asked the users to like the facebook application profile page for my app, so that when I post news on that wall, the users get it. This causes some confusion since the application profile page is a bit of a peripheral component in the webapp-facebook relationship.

Ideally I would be able to post on facebook either as the app, so that I reach all the registered users, or as the app url (www.myapp.url) so that users who like that url will get the posts. Alternatively somehow link the application profile page and the url/app, so that likers of the url or users of the app get the profile page posts.

Note that I'm not looking to post to users walls (just their feeds) and I'd prefer to post manually, using facebooks interface for posting.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways you can publish into a user's news feed is to use a Facebook Page or a Facebook Open Graph Object.  So, you did right by asking users to like your Facebook Application Page.  If you've also got a webpage that people like, you can turn that webpage into an Open Graph object by adding an `fb:app_id` or `fb:admins` meta tag to the head of the page.  Doing this grants you access to publish to your fans' news feeds, and you get access to a Facebook page-like interface (for administration purposes only).  You can publish to the user's feed using this feed publisher (just like you would do if your Graph object were any other Facebook Page).

To get to the admin page you just have to make sure your Facebook User ID is in the `fb:admins` meta tag.  Once it is, visit a like button social widget for that object, and you'll get the a link that lets you go to the admin page for the object.

I hope that's clear.  You should probably give the [Open Graph Protocol Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#admin) a good read.

Comment: It's halfway clear, in that what I want to do doesn't seem possible. I've done everything you mention, which means I have both a facebook page and a facebook app (with an app profile page), so two places to post updates to. What I would prefer is to merge the fans of the page with the fans of the app, so that when a user clicks like, they like the app and in their feed the like shows up with a link to the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't merge your fans from 2 different entities.  You'll have to pick one and stick with it.  In order to get the automatic feed story share on a like, you need to use the Open Graph protocol and make sure your page has the appropriate Open Graph tags, `og:title`, `og:image`, `og:url`, `og:description`, and `fb:admins`